# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, oracle, parsing, indexoutofboundsexception

I got the following exception in my program :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at id.co.ptap.text.ParseText.main(ParseText.java:370)
```

This is the relevant code:

```
        x = first+";"+allHeader.get(count) + strBody + "\n"; //line 370
        bw.write(x);
        System.out.println(x);

            if (ketemu) {                   
                count++;
                ketemu = false;
            }
```

Comment: `allHeader` size is less than from `count`.

Comment: You already posted the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707733/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-1-size-1

Comment: I have chosen to close the other as a duplicate of this since this one has answers and is at least somewhat of an improvement, and I have chosen to close *this* one as a duplicate of an easily findable existing question on the general topic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, based on the error `allHeader` is an `ArrayList` with a single item, and `count == 1`. The max index accepted by `allHeader.get(count)` is `allHeader.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`allHeader.get(count)`

will give you this **Exception**

check value of **Count**.

because you are trying to access value that **doesn't have matching index number for ArrayList** you have to access value from ArrayList which is less than size of ArrayList.
(i.e value of count should be less than size of ArrayList)

`count < ArrayList.size()`

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList indexes start at `0`, and go up to `size() - 1`. So if you have 1 item, it is at index `0`, not `1`. Change the following line to:

```
**x = first+";"+allHeader.get(count-1) + strBody + "\n";** //line 370
```

That would get the last item in the ArrayList, assuming `count` is equal to `allHeader.size()`

Comment: i already try but this exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at id.co.ptap.text.ParseText.main(ParseText.java:370)

Comment: Is `count` equal to `allHeader.size()`? The only way you'd get an IndexOutOfBounds at `-1` using the above code is if count was `0`, which means that there are no items in the ArrayList.